# Blackjack program class organization c++ OOP best practices

Tags: c++, class, blackjack

I wrote a blackjack program and this question is more about the design / organization than a coding error.  (is that allowed?)

I created a playing card class and then created a vector of 52 playing cards as my deck.  I created some basic functions for things like drawing a card from the deck when a player hits or for shuffling the deck.

My question is how should I organize those deck functions?  Should I have made a deck class with my playing card class nested inside, and then simply have the deck functions as part of the deck class?

I am trying to gain a better understanding of best practices in OOP but am a bit stuck here.  Thanks.

Comment: I'd rather say you should ask in a different network. How about Programmers? Or something with Game in it?

Comment: Code review probably works too assuming you have a working program in need of review.

Comment: Hint:  A deck is a container of cards.  A deck can be shuffled.  One can remove cards from a deck.  One can add cards to a deck.  My preference is no nested classes.  Nested classes are difficult to reuse by other classes.

Comment: My advice: don't overdo OOP for the sake of complying with OOP. A more useful rule is "don't use global variables".